# Maintain a dynamic link distance among nodes in force layout D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am parsing link distance for each link in json string.

```
 {
  "nodes" : [ {
    "name" : "cricket",
    "category" : "main",
    "id" : 0
  }, {
    "name" : "record1",
    "category" : "twitter",
    "id" : 1
  }, {
    "name" : "record2",
    "category" : "web",
    "id" : 2
  }],
  "links" : [ {
    "source" : 0,
    "target" : 1,
    "linkDistance" : 13.17538
  }, {
    "source" : 0,
    "target" : 2,
    "linkDistance" : 13.17538
  } ]
}
```

In the javascript, link distance is given as a function.

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
     .gravity(0.3)
     .charge(0)
     .size([width,height])
     .nodes(jsonstring.nodes)
     .links(jsonstring.links)
     .linkDistance(function (d) {
           return d.linkDistance;
     })
     .start();
```

But the nodes are not drawing in the given link distance. The charge value is 0. Does anybody have an idea of how to maintain dynamic link distances when it is parsed through json?

Comment: Set up a fiddle so we can take a look

Comment: Link distance in D3's force layout is best be considered a wish rather than a restriction. It is taken into account when calculating the forces, but it is not guaranteed to have this exact length and most likely will differ to some degree. For an explanation see my [answer](/a/34376334/4235784) to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your `d.linkDistance` is edited, you need to call again

```
force.linkDistance(function (d) {
       return d.linkDistance;
 })
```

for the modification to take effect.

Also remember that link distance is only very weakly enforced in `d3`, so that from my experience editing link distance does not have a large effect on the graph layout anyway. You can always try `force.linkStrength(10)` or higher values to increase the importance of your distance, but this might not be enough to have *precisely* the right values.

---

Something to try:

- find a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) of your graph (this gives a list of edges being a "skeleton" `st`)
- run the following to enforce the edge length is correct:

  ```
  force.on('tick', function() {
     //consider all edges of a spanning tree, from root to leaves
     //using links directly instead of st would yield strange results, but depending on your data it might work well enough
     st.forEach(function(d) {
         //compute link coordinates  
         var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x; 
         var dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
         //ratio desired length / actual length
         var r = d.linkDistance / Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) 
         //add r=Math.sqrt(r) for something smoother (but less constrained)
         //move target to desired length
         d.target.x = d.source.x + dx * r; 
         d.target.y = d.source.y + dy * r;

     })
  })
  ```

It will badly degrade the natural flow of the force layout (maybe a bit less with `r=Math.sqrt(r)`, but still), and it will mess up with node drag if you use that, but it should enforce some arc length when possible.

Comment: Thanks laurent for your answer. I edited the json string to explain this clearly. My problem is that as you can see the 3 nodes with the two links (0--->1) and (0--->2) are with **same link distance** (13.17538). But it is not drawing in the same distance.

Comment: See my edit, you can increase link strength to try and get similar distances (or reduce other parameters: charge and gravity), but in any case d3 does not guarantee that link distance should be correct.

Comment: Thanks laurent. Can you suggest any other library that fulfill my requirement?

Comment: @SulariFernando sorry I don't know any other. I'll try to write a piece of code to run after ticks, that my do the trick.

Comment: @SulariFernando What exactly is your objective? I suppose, you want to maintain a **fixed** link distance rather than the **dynamic** distance you mentioned in the title, right?

Comment: @altocumulus I want to maintain the distances I give via the json for each link. It may differ from one another.